# How to write a c program to create a file?

Tags: c, file, structure

I want to create a file by importing the file name from the user, please help

```
int file_name;
printf("Enter ID NUMBER : ");
scanf("%d",&file_name);
FILE *fin;
fin = fopen(&file_name , "w");
```

Comment: You are passing an `int *` as the first argument to `fopen`. This is wrong. The `fopen` function takes a `char *` pointing to a null-terminated filename string as its first argument, not an `int *`.

Comment: The file name has to be a string: `char file_name[1024]; scanf("%1023s", file_name); FILE *fin = fopen(file_name , "w");`

Comment: I want to record and display user's informations but not working please help this is my term project

[1]: https://i.hizliresim.com/4j4Mzp.png "ScreenShot"

Comment: copy/paste the text contents of the linked file into your question.  We cannot access the linked .PNG file, the result of trying to access it is:  `403 Forbidden`

Comment: I would suggest using: `open()` to create the file, as you then have control over its' access permissions, etc

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
FILE *fin;
fin = fopen(&file_name , "w"); /* this is wrong, since &file_name is of int* type */
```

`fopen()` expects first argument of `char*` type but you have provided as of `int*` type which is wrong, and which has been reported by compiler correctly as

> **error**: incompatible pointer types passing
>         `'int *'` to parameter of type `'const char *'`
>         [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

if you could have compiled with flag like
`-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`. From the manual page of [fopen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

> FILE *fopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode);

Declare `file_name` as *array of characters* & store the name of file into it.

```
char file_name[1024]; /* take a char array to store file name */
/* @TODO : store actual file name into file_name array */
FILE *fin = fopen(file_name , "w");
if(fin == NULL) {
  /* @TODO : error handling */
}
```

Comment: I want to record and display user's informations but not working please help this is my term project

[1]: https://i.hizliresim.com/4j4Mzp.png "ScreenShot"

Comment: Please edit the question & paste in question itself. I can'see it in my system.

Comment: please can you share your email adress to me ? because ı can't paste codes here.

Comment: any/everybody can post text into their own question.  So post the text into your question.